# Tag Merge Request: [bignum], [bignumber], [largenumber], etc

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

The following tags all refer to handling of large numbers:

- [bignum](/questions/tagged/bignum) - 93 questions
- [big-number](/questions/tagged/big-number) - 3 questions
- [largenumber](/questions/tagged/largenumber) - 46 questions
- [large-number](/questions/tagged/large-number) - 6 questions
- [arbitrary-precision](/questions/tagged/arbitrary-precision) - 55 questions

I'm not sure what they should be merged into. Though I'm leaning towards [arbitrary-precision](/questions/tagged/arbitrary-precision) since that's the most descriptive of them.

Comment: Though I could imagine the first four being used for long integers and the last one used for real numbers that aren't integers. Am I alone on that?

Comment: I considered that too, but looking at the questions tagged with those, there doesn't seem to be a distinction. So even if they are kept separate, they'll continued to be mis-tagged with each other.

Comment: Aha; if we're going to fight against entropy, we might as well pick our battles accordingly. Then let me cast my vote for `arbitrary-precision`. :)